# TYPO3 excludeUidList is there an includeUidList

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Have search the net, for a solution where i have a navi TS file that show a Menu.
here i only want to show 2 links, the links are a Main root page and a sub page, so my question is.

If i dont want to excludeUidList all the 7-9 Uid, is there a way to make a includeUidList ?

bc i can't get this to work, it showing all the Uid links.

```
lib.leftNavi = HMENU
lib.leftNavi.entryLevel=0
lib.leftNavi.includeUidList = 4,8
lib.leftNavi.1 = TMENU
lib.leftNavi.1 {
  wrap = <div id="leftMenu"><ul class="L1"><li><ul>|</ul></li></ul></div>
  expAll = 0
  NO = 1
  NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
  NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
  RO < .NO
  RO = 1
  CUR < .NO
  CUR = 1
  CUR.allWrap = <li class="current">|</li>
  CUR.stdWrap.wrap = <span>|</span>
  CUR.ATagParams =  
  ACT < .CUR
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no includeUidList, see the reference at http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/ContentObjects/Hmenu/.

But you can use a HMENU with the "special" property: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/ContentObjects/Hmenu/#hmenu-special-property

```
20 = HMENU
20.special = list
20.special.value = 35, 56
```

This will generate a menu with page 35 and 36.

Comment: dang, 5 seconds faster!

Comment: Good answer but I have a suggestion: Demonstrate what you mean by providing modified version of the code from the question instead of some unrelated code sample. That will make it easier to follow for all the people in future as they will see the original and modified code.

Comment: Cascaval u'r right, but I added the code after lorenz, was so quick to give me an answer, so he did answer the question - out from the info i provided, the code was added after he lay the answer.   but thx to all.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen: Oh, right. There should be a slow motion mode added to Stack Overflow so that people can keep up with you guys. :-)